# Reverse a sublist of a doubly linked list

Tags: algorithm, reverse, doubly-linked-list

I recently came up with a problem, and with some reading I understood that there's a way to reverse a doubly linked list in constant time, just by swapping head and tail pointers.

Now, thinking of a slightly different version of the problem, if we want to reverse just a sublist of the doubly linked list (from x to y), how could it be done?

`0->1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->9` with (`x = 2, y = 7`)
would become:
`0->1->7->6->5->4->3->2->8->9`

Answer (score 2):

You can but you mess the linked list a lot.
Basically we add a bit to each node that says if you should reverse order at this point.
Next you modify the iterator to xor all these new bits it's seen so far.

The iterator will now pick next/prev or prev/next depending on the xor of the bits.

Now you can reverse arbitrary intervals in the linked list in O(1), BUT you loose iterator consistency: any swap operation might invalidate existing iterators. Also the code will be very confusing so I would avoid it if at all possible.

To do the actual flip you change (add null-checking to make sure you don't crash)

```
 (first->prev,last->next) = (last->next, first->prev)
 last->next->next = last
 first->prev->prev = first
 last.reverse_here = !last.reverse_here
 first->prev.reverse_here = !first->prev.reverse_here
 Invalidate_all_existing_iterators()
```

Draw it on paper because it's very confusing.

Comment: great @Sorin, just a thing, could you provide me a basic  java implementation?

Comment: I think I don't understand the 2nd and 3rd line
```last->next->next = last 
first->prev->prev = first ```

Comment: @geek4079, I would stay as far away as possible from an implementation. There's lots of thing that you can get wrong. You have the pseudo-code above. If you're really into it I'm sure you can code it yourself.

Comment: yeah you're right, can you just explain me the 2nd and 3rd line above?

Comment: @geek4079 those set the pointers from outside the swapped interval. What was before the first node (last->next) needs to point to the last node as the next node, and what was after the last node (first->prev) needs to point to the first node as the previous node. Draw it on paper.

Comment: @Sorin - I dont get it... If I have n=1000 and x=250, y=750, how you connect 250->751 in O(1)? You have to iterate to 250 and to 750 to select the nodes which takes you O(n) time.

Comment: Done, but I'm already struggling with that: would be very kind of you explaining it taking my example from the question

Comment: @libik You can if you already have iterators pointing at 250 and 750(input). Then it's just pointer juggling.

Answer (score 0):

```
way to reverse a doubly linked list in constant time
```

It is not possible, however it is possible in linear time `O(n)`

Answer to question : You have to manage "start" and "end" differently than the rest. If you start from 7 and goes to 2, you remember this pointer 7-> and store it in variable X. It stores pointer to 8. Then you continue as usual.

When you reach the 2, you put 2.head = X.

The similar thing must be done for 1->7, but you should figure it out.

---

Edit about constant time : you can rewrite iterator in constant time, however the data structure itself remains unchanged. Therefore with only changing iterator, you cant take reversed data itself and do some stuff with it - because it is not really reversed.

---

PS : In arraylist you can change iterator in constant time even for sublist.

Comment: @geek4079  Do you want to apply dirty trick with `getNext(Node<T> node) {return node.previous;` to three parts by different way and store information about implicit link inversion in some data structure?

Comment: that could be an idea

Comment: @geek4079 That reverses the entire list, not a sublist.

Comment: @geek4079 - it is way to iterate through list reversed in constant time, it is something different.